# Connect to DigitalOcean MySQL Database with CA certificate (.crt)

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to connect to a mysql database with a ca-certificate.

The database is protected with a SSL CA Certificate, and to connect via MySQL Workbench I use this :

[image]

When connecting to MySQL Workbench it works perfectly, but is not working when I try to connect via an Java Application.

Apparently from similar questions, the MySQL documentation is not updated properly. This is the connection string I'm using:

```
jdbc:mysql://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[database]?useSSL=true&sslMode=VERIFY_CA&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:[absolute-path-to-crt-file]
```

Tomcat Logs:

```
Caused by: com.cbre.common.fwk.throwable.DalException: Failed to get connection for ''
        at com.cbre.dal.ConnectionUtil.getConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:32)
        at com.cbre.dao.OpportunityDao.getAllOpportunities(OpportunityDao.java:130)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file: [Invalid keystore format]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:70)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
        at com.cbre.dal.ConnectionUtil.getConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:28)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.SSLParamsException: Cannot open file: [Invalid keystore format]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:546)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:301)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:206)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:347)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:796)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:503)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:220)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1443)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:952)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:667)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:518)
        ... 44 more
```

Comment: _"java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format"_ You need to use a Java Keystore (JKS) file, not CRT. See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Where did you read that on the link? Can't find that.

Comment: That's implied by the use of `keytool` in that documentation, and made explicit by the stacktrace in the question as it uses `sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore` which is the class that reads JKS files.